# Convert an XML to XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to make an XSLT from an XML file I have done it but I don't know if there is any better way more automatic way that the one I have done.

Here is my solution:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<onlinecomputer>
    <item name="Processor" price="100.00"/>
        <item name="USB driver" price="50.00"/>
        <item name="Webcam" price="20.50"/>
        <item name="Notebook" price="700.00"/>
        <place>
         <name>Prishtin</name>
           <customer>
                <name>Hana</name>
                <street> Nen Tereza</street>
                <order item="Processor" amount="1"/>
                <order item="USB driver" amount="3"/>
                <order item="Webcam" amount="3"/>
                <order item="Notebook" amount="2"/>
           </customer>
            <customer>
                <name>Ron</name>
                <street> blbl</street>
                <order item="Webcam" amount="1"/>
           </customer>
      </place>
        <place>
         <name>Tetove</name>
           <customer>
                <name>Edin</name>
                <street> gggg</street>
                <order item="Processor" amount="4"/>
                <order item="Notebook" amount="1"/>
           </customer>
            <customer>
                <name>Alex</name>
                <street> bbbb</street>
                <order item="Processor" amount="2"/>
           </customer>
      </place>
</onlinecomputer>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Order</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="onlinecomputer/place/customer/order">     
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="../name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@item"/></td>
      </tr>      
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If anyone can help me please do so cause I need it for tomorrow.

Comment: An XSLT file processes an XML file to produce some output. It is unclear from your question whether you want to generate an XML file using XSLT, or whether you want to process an XML file using XSLT. Your example indicates the latter, and no - there would be millions of correct ways to process an XML file using XSLT - it all depends on what output is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is good. But, there is another way called "Simplifed stylesheet" where you needn't declare stylesheet or templates:

```
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="2.0">
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Order</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="
        onlinecomputer/place/customer/order">     
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@item"/>
                </td>
            </tr>      
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```